# What is new in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Couldn't find any compiled info on new things in rails 3. Nor release date.

Answer (score 1):

From http://mcphersonz.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/key-features-for-rails-v2-2-rails-v2-3-and-the-upcoming-rails-v3-0/

- Lock up all the unicorns. You can’t please everyone all the time, so don’t focus on the unicorns.
- No holy cows. Nothing is sacred in rails & everything is up for debate. Don’t look any anything we have & feel like that is the way it has to be.
  Major Themes:
- New routes. Faster, route by subdomain, user agents, etc. Rack to other rack machinery.
- XSS protection (cross side injection). By default all output in views will be escaped. No more use of <%= h something %>. Assumed by default.
- Javascript goes Unobtrusive & Agnostic. Much less JS is injected into page & instead unobtrusive JS is used to achieve same effect.
- More Agnosticism.
- Action ORM is a slim proxy wrapper for ORM tools that allows for easy swapping of ORM implementation,
- Generators (script/generator) will for example allow you to specify that rspec is used, so script/generate model will create a rspec test file for model.
- Refactoring
- Abstract Controller takes similarities between for example ActionController & ActionMailer and combines them into one code base.
- Cherry picking from ActiveSupport allowing you to pick parts that are used instead of pulling in the entire library.
- Increased performance / speed with callbacks.